# What is causing these artifacts when using booleans?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm attempting to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNba2oEij2c) one minute tutorial on creating post-apocalyptic buildings. The dude goes hilariously fast But I think I must have missed something. After I create a cube and use the subdivide tool to make it an object to take a "bite" out of the buildings, I get the following artifacts:

[image: extra edges appearing on the object]

It appears the extra edges are caused by a discrepancy in the size of the faces on the blob and the building. In the video he has no such errors. I've tried playing the video at slower speeds but I don't see anything different.

[image]

Comment: I start by giving -1 in the video, it is quite confusing, and if you are a newbie you will obviously feel lost along the way

Comment: Did you notice that it duplicates the object with which it applies the boolean and scales it by reducing the size? you did that ?

Comment: yes, I duplicated the object and scaled it. I think that's for the internal rebar structure.